# Disable gesture recognizer in AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, avkit

In `AVPlayerViewController` there is a feature for stopping the playback of a video and closing the `AVPlayerViewController` by swiping its view.

I want to disable this feature. I guess I need to disable a gesture recognizer!?

But I don’t know how to do this for the player.

Comment: are you using an `AVPlayerController`?

Comment: I'm using AVPlayerViewController. Don't know if that's the same thing? @MilanNosáľ

Comment: I don't have time right now, but I'll take a look at it a bit later today

Comment: Thank you @MilanNosáľ :)

Comment: can you share the code that you already have?

Answer (score 3):

I recently stumbled upon a similar problem. You can access the gesture recognizers from the `contentView` of `AVPlayerViewController`.

If you wanted to keep only the tap gesture recognizer, you might want to use a function like this:

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {
    func disableGestureRecognition() {
        let contentView = view.value(forKey: "contentView") as? UIView
        contentView?.gestureRecognizers = contentView?.gestureRecognizers?.filter { $0 is UITapGestureRecognizer }
    }
}
```

Comment: Work for me, thanks but is dangerous to use private property.QQ

Answer (score 1):

Removing gestures didn't worked for me. Adding a new `UIPanGestureRecognizer` without any action worked.

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {
    func disableGesture() {
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me, instead I used simply this one:
(iOS 16)

```
controller.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```