# unable to catch swipe gesture on AVPlayerViewController using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, avplayerviewcontroller

I want to check if swipe gesture working or not on AVPlayer video.
I tried a small sample app to do so but it did not work. Not sure why code is not working.

On button tap, below is the code:

```
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
var player: AVPlayer?

        let videoUrlString = "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
        let videoURL = URL(string: videoUrlString)
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.player?.play()
        })

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up

        playerViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

@objc func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        if (sender.direction == .left) {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Swipe Action", message: "It is LEFT Swipe ", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true
        }
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: you have added swipe direction to up and handled left one. isn't an issue?

Comment: @RMRAHUL - any direction is fine, at least it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you need to [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48538156/disable-gesture-recognizer-in-avplayerviewcontroller) `AVPlayerViewController`'s default `gestureRecognizers` for that you can use

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {
    func disableGestureRecognition() {
        let contentView = view.value(forKey: "contentView") as? UIView
        contentView?.gestureRecognizers = contentView?.gestureRecognizers?.filter { $0 is UITapGestureRecognizer }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
playerViewController.disableGestureRecognition()
```

Now you need to replace

```
leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up
```

with

```
leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left
```

because you are checking for `left` direction.

And since your `UIViewController` is not longer in window hierarchy you can not present alert with `self.present` and to solve that you need to make `playerViewController` as a global variable in your class.

and then you can present alert like:

```
playerViewController.present(alert, animated: true)
```

in your `handleSwipes` method.

And working code will be like:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
    var player: AVPlayer?
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func tap(_ sender: Any) {

        let videoUrlString = "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
        let videoURL = URL(string: videoUrlString)
        self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)

        playerViewController.player = player

        playerViewController.disableGestureRecognition()
        present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.player?.play()
        })

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left
        playerViewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    }

    @objc func handleSwipes(_ sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        if (sender.direction == .left) {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Swipe Action", message: "It is LEFT Swipe ", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            playerViewController.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

extension AVPlayerViewController {
    func disableGestureRecognition() {
        let contentView = view.value(forKey: "contentView") as? UIView
        contentView?.gestureRecognizers = contentView?.gestureRecognizers?.filter { $0 is UITapGestureRecognizer }
    }
}
```

And result will be:

[image]

Comment: for me still not working, used exact same code as per above.

Comment: Check out this demo project https://github.com/KheniDharmesh/Guesture-With-AVPlayer

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the user interactions on your view?

```
playerViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

I don't know the player but you should read the doc, maybe it already catches the swipe gestures and provides an API to use it.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `delegate` for `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, i.e.

```
leftSwipe.delegate = self
```

And conform your `viewController` to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    //Rest of the code
}
```